# Coq/SSReflect: standard way to case on (x < y) + (x == y) + (y < x)?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ssreflect

In vanilla Coq, I'd write

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
Goal nat -> nat -> False.
  intros n m.
  destruct (lt_eq_lt_dec n m) as [[?|?]|?].
```

to get three goals, one for `n < m`, one for `n = m`, and one for `m < n`.
In ssreflect, I'd start with

```
From Coq.ssr Require Import ssreflect ssrbool.
From mathcomp.ssreflect Require Import eqtype ssrnat.
Goal nat -> nat -> False.
  move => n m.
```

What's the standard/canonical way to divide this into three cases, for `n < m`, `n == m`, and `m < n`, in ssreflect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ltngtP`:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool eqtype ssrnat.
Goal nat -> nat -> False.
  move => n m.
  case: (ltngtP n m) => [n_lt_m|m_lt_n|n_eq_m].
```

In accordance with the ssreflect style, this lemma automatically simplifies comparison functions such as `n < m`, `n == m`, etc. in the goal.

Comment: You may prefer to feed the expression you are interested as the index of the ltngtP predicate, thus `case: (n < m) / ltngtP => ...` , it usually comes in handy [and helps understanding the default behavior for just `case: ltngtP`.

Comment: Also the last case will give you `n = m`, i.e., the propositional equality. If you need `n==m`, change the last part to `...|/eqP n_eq_m].`

Comment: I recommend
`From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool eqtype ssrnat.`
for the imports, (note that `order` is not necessary here, `ssrfun` is mandatory, and `mathcomp` ones should be priviledged over Coq's (which might be older))